# How to resolve an error in the difference of two date columns of a pandas date frame

Tags: python, date, difference

I have to make the difference of two dates in number of days. I can not reproduce the real case but I ask for an opinion. My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df['date1']=pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
df['date2']=pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])
df['date3'] = df['date1'].subtract(df['date2']).dt.days
```

return the error:

```
IndexError: unsupported iterator index
```

Comment: Looks like you may need [timedeltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html)